# How to have a field placeholder for a function in a data class

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

Consider the fallowing:

I have a data class and one of the fields will receive a function in the future.

What type should I declarer the variable?
Also, I set a value of None as the init value, is that the right thing to do?

```
@dataclass
class SystemIpMember:
    name: str
    ip: str
    verify_func: ??? = None
    online: bool = False
```

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe it is better to have two dataclasses - one with this field, and one without. Class without this field will have `with_function` method, which return class with this field.

Comment: I still dont know what should be the data type of the function field

Comment: For function type you can use [`typing.Callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable).

Comment: Thanks! I will use that.

Answer (score 0):

As Max Stated, I used "Callable"

```
@dataclass
class SystemIpMember:
    name: str
    ip: str
    verify_func: Callable = None
    online: bool = False
```